# Logging through custom log4j in Spark program triggered from Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, logging

I need to trigger a spark program from my java utility and I would need to log the statements of the java program and the spark logs in the same file in the file system.

I tried using setConf, addSparkArg , --driver-java-options on the SparkLauncher  but to no avail.

Is it possible to log the statements onto the same file for both the java and spark.If so how can i do it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** when you spin up the SparkLauncher programmatically, you could redirect logging to application logger using:
`redirectToLog` as in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html#redirectToLog-java.lang.String-
Ex:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
//in your launcher init method.
SparkLauncher sparkLauncher = new SparkLauncher();
sparkLauncher.redirectToLog(LOG.getName());
```

The Logger here is SLF4J.

**Option 2**
As far as I know, Spark uses log4j by default (you may use slf4j with logback if you wish). You could configure log4j in your application which will be available on your CLASSPATH. For example you may include javaOptions in built.sbt:

```
javaOptions in run ++= Seq(
  "-Dlog4j.debug=true",
  "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties")
```

and place the log4j.properties in `src/main/resources`. The default spark log4j properties template should be available at `$SPARK_HOME/conf` which you could use to configure loggers.

Comment: How do we set this to the SparkLauncher in java.Can you elaborate plz.

Comment: Thanks but the redirectToLog is available in newer versions , how about 2.0 and previous versions. How can we set the log4j.configuration to the sparklauncher?

Comment: Nope, the execution is done from the maven project -> java code so would need to set it within the java code

Comment: Well, you should still have a `/src/main/resources`.Why is it impossible?